# Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default network: HNS failed with error : The object already exists

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016

I am getting a Daemon error while start starting docker services.

```
- System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  docker 
 
  - EventID 4 

   [ Qualifiers]  0 
 
   Level 2 
 
   Task 0 
 
   Keywords 0x80000000000000 
 
  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2021-05-20T11:56:33.780842300Z 
 
   EventRecordID 404284 
 
   Channel Application 
 
   Computer Computer.Name
 
   Security 
 

- EventData


    Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default network: HNS failed with error: The object already exists.
```

Error details from event viewer:

```
fatal: Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default network: HNS failed with error: The object already exists.
```

Docker Command: `start-service docker`

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused due to a custom `NAT` entry. Try removing the `NAT` then the issue would be resolved

Check-in `PowerShell`:

1. `Get-NetNat`, if anything is returned,
2. try removing with the command `Remove-NetNat`

Comment: Thanks, Ashok. Nothing is returned from PowerShell with the command Get-NetNat.